# Why does ISO C / POSIX time() have an optional pointer argument

Tags: c, posix, standard, api

ISO C / POSIX [declare](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/time.html) the `time()` function like this:

```
time_t time(time_t *tloc);
```

The documentation says:

> The time() function shall return the value of time in seconds since
> the Epoch.
>
> The tloc argument points to an area where the return value is also
> stored. If tloc is a null pointer, no value is stored.

I don't see why one would design the API from the start in such a way that there was both a return value and an "out" parameter. Is there a good rationale for designing it like that or did this evolve historically?

Was there at some point in the past a `time()` function that just had the out parameter (`void time(time_t *)`), but it was changed to a `time_t` return value, with the first parameter being kept for backwards compatibility?

Or alternatively, were there systems where the return value was restricted in size that didn't fit a `time_t`, so a pointer was needed?

Comment: When that function was coded... C had no type long but time was reported on 32bits. => The need for some memory address where the function could store an array of 2 (16bits) ints.

Answer (score 2):

So as MC68020 said in the comments, C didn't have a `long` type back then, the oldest occurrence I could find is in [lib/time.s](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V2/lib/time.s) of Second Edition Unix, the file is dated 1972-06-07 on that website linked above, with this source (PDP-11 assembly):

```
/ C library -- time

/ tvec = time(tvec);
/
/ tvec[0], tvec[1] contain the time

    .globl  _time

.data
_time:
    1f
.text
1:
    mov 2(sp),r0
    sys time
    mov ac,(r0)
    mov mq,2(r0)
    rts pc
```

Interestingly, it seems like it always had the return value (`tvec = time(tvec);`), assuming `tvec` is some kind of 2-component array of 16-bit values, if that assignment has any relevance.